# How do I run cucumber test from a .feature file in java?

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, cucumber

I have currently made this feature file:

```
Feature: Open up google chrome and go to news.google.ca

Scenario: Open google news
Then I open google news
```

And these are my step defs where I created this part:

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class MyStepdefs {
@Then("^I open google news$")
public void I_open_google_news() throws Throwable {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://news.google.ca/");
}
}
```

However when I go back to my feature file and try running my scenario:
[image]
I get this error from IntelliJ:

```
You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Then("^I open google news$")
public void I_open_google_news() throws Throwable {
// Express the Regexp above with the code you wish you had
throw new PendingException();
}







Undefined step: Then  I open google news




1 scenario (0 passed)


1 steps (0 passed)


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I still get this errro even though I've made my steps already. How do I fix this and run my feature file in java from intellij
can anyone help me :(

Comment: you haven't glued your definition class properly share with me image of your project and classes

Comment: Hi @fahad, I will update this comment with an image of the file structure later in the day